# Conditional aspect using a configuration file

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Using spring 3.2 and AspectJ 1.6, I've implemented a profiling aspect with AspectJ to get performance metrics of my application.

It is working, but now I need that the execution of this aspect was conditional. I mean, this profiling is only usefull some times, so I would like to switch off it when it isn't needed.

The first approach that I made was to add a new property that is injected by spring to the aspect. Then this property is used to make the execution conditional. Something like this:

Aspect:

```
...
private boolean active;
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicOperation() {
}
@Around("anyPublicOperation()")
public Object profile(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
    throws Throwable {
if (active){
            ...
    }
}
```

Bean configuration:

```
<!-- Profiling aspect -->
<bean class="example.ProfilingAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
    <property name="active" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

This works, but I'd like to desactive it completely to avoid the execution of the aspect then it isn't needed.

However, the only solution that I found was to comment the aspect in the 'aop.xml' file, but I'd prefer to use a property to activate/desactivate the profiling.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you could create two aop.xml files... one normal and one for profiling. choose the profiling one with this argument:

```
-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=META-INF/aop-profiling.xml
```

or you could check in the aspect, if it should do any work... but i would not do it that way...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that it's a web application, so I can't configure it this way since we can't add configuration to how the web server is executed. By the way, I've also added to the question the solution that I had implemented. But I dont like it neither. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in following manner :

1. Declare a property in your property file, which tells whether aspect should be enabled or disabled .
   Eg : `enableAspect =true`
2. create two aspect classes extending an abstract class :

   ```
               AbstractAspectClass (contains blank implementation of advices)
                      /     \
                     /        \
                    /           \
       EnableAspectClass           DisableAspectClass
   ```

   (contains all the required advices     (doesnt contain any method)
   with implemenattion)

3) Create a bean class which will return the required Aspect based on property

```
@Bean
public AbstractAspectClass abstractAspectClass() {

    return enabeAspect ? new EnableAspectClass() : new DisableAspectClass();
}
```

Comment: Its a good idea, but the problem can be more complicated if I just need some method inside that Class.
Wishing Spring has way to make  aspect annotation working with Spring expression